# PyMEL vs cmds Maya Autodesk

Tags: maya

I need to replace all `pymel.core` func with `maya.cmds` (Maya Autodesk)
How to replace `PyNode(node_name)`, what is analog?

Trying to find "one row" function, somehting like cmds.Node?? Does such function exist? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct 1:1 translation. Pymel wraps Maya nodes into objects whereas cmds simply use and return strings. I suppose you will have to recreate the scripts by hand or try with the help of a machine learning tool.